# Why does my code cause a nullpointer?

Tags: java

This is the exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.rs.net.decoders.handlers.InventoryOptionsHandler$2.run(InventoryOptionsHandler.java:512)
    at com.rs.game.player.CoordsEvent.processEvent(CoordsEvent.java:55)
    at com.rs.game.player.Player.processEntity(Player.java:357)
    at com.rs.cores.WorldProcessor.process(WorldProcessor.java:39)
    at com.rs.cores.PriorityProcessor.run(PriorityProcessor.java:10)
```

Here is the code:

InventoryOptionsHandler:

```
if (object.getId() == 15621) {
    player.getWarriorsGuild().createWarrior(itemId, object);
    player.getDialogueManager().startDialogue(
         (short) 211,
         new String[] {
             "The animator hums. Something seems to be working.",
             "You stand back..." });
    return;
}
```

Now my getWarriorsGuild() Method in player.java

```
public AnimationGame getWarriorsGuild() {
    return warriorsGuild;
}

public AnimationGame warriorsGuild = new AnimationGame(this);
```

and last but not least, my createWarrior method in AnimationGame.

```
public void createWarrior(int armours, final WorldObject object) {
    final WarriorsArmour sets = WarriorsArmour.forId(armours);
    if (sets == null || sets.getArmour() == null) return;
    if (sets.getArmour()[0] == armours || sets.getArmour()[1] == armours
            || sets.getArmour()[2] == armours) {
        if (player.getInventory().containsItem(sets.getArmour()[0], 1)
                && player.getInventory().containsItem(sets.getArmour()[1],
                        1)
                && player.getInventory().containsItem(sets.getArmour()[2],
                        1)) {
            final boolean running = player.isRunning();
            player.getInventory().deleteItem(sets.getArmour()[0], 1);
            player.getInventory().deleteItem(sets.getArmour()[1], 1);
            player.getInventory().deleteItem(sets.getArmour()[2], 1);
            int newX = player.getX();
            int newY = player.getY() + 5;
            player.setRun(false);
            player.setRunHidden(false);
            player.addWalkSteps(newX, newY, -1, false);
            player.setNextAnimation(new Animation(827));
            player.addStopDelay(3L);
            player.getDialogueManager().startDialogue("WAnimator",
                    new Object[0]);
            WorldTasksManager.schedule(new WorldTask() {

                public void run() {
                    if (!secondloop) {
                        secondloop = true;
                        player.setRunHidden(running);
                    } else {
                        stop();
                    }
                }

                boolean secondloop;
            }, 0, 6);
            WorldTasksManager.schedule(new WorldTask() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    final NPC war = new NPC(sets.getNpcId(), new WorldTile(
                            object.getX(), object.getY(), 0), -1, true);
                    war.addWalkSteps(player.getY(), player.getY());
                    player.setNextFaceEntity(war);
                    war.setTarget(player);
                    war.setNextAnimation(new Animation(4166));
                    war.setNextForceTalk(new ForceTalk("I'M ALIVE!"));
                    player.getInterfaceManager().closeChatBoxInterface();
                    player.getInterfaceManager()
                            .closeReplacedRealChatBoxInterface();
                    player.getHintIconsManager().addHintIcon(war, 1, -1,
                            false);
                    player.sendAreaInterface(player);
                    WorldTasksManager.schedule(new WorldTask() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            war.setFinished(true);
                            war.setForceWalk(new WorldTile(-1, -1, -1));
                            World.removeNPC(war);
                            stop();
                        }

                    }, 60, 60);
                    stop();
                    return;
                }

            }, 3, 3);
        } else {
            return;
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

I would like to know, what is causing that nullpointer, as I do not understand?
If you need to see more, dont hesitate to ask, thanks :)

Comment: Well, what line throws the exception?? You don't give nearly enough information for this question to be answerable. A variable on the line that throws the NPE is null, and you will first need to find out which variable (println's can help with this), then backtrack through your code to see why it is null.

Comment: 512 in InventoryOptionsHandler, (Where its calling getWarriorsGuild()

Comment: Then either the player variable is null or the `getWarriorsGuild()` method is returning null. On the line above the offending line, add this line: `System.out.println("player is null: " + (player == null));` and see what gets returned.

Comment: player is null: false, that's what it says.

Comment: Then the method `getWarriorsGuild()` is returning null and you're trying to call a method off of a null. I hate to say this, but we may need to see more code.

Comment: Make sure player isn't null, try putting player, getWarriorsGuild on different lines.
Also, if this is for RareBot, I would not be with them as they have legal issues.

Comment: Hmm, well it doesnt seem like its returning null. And no this is for my rsps.

Comment: Fixed it.
Had to change getWarriorsGuild()
To
 public AnimationGame getWarriorsGuild() {
  if (warriorsGuild == null)
   warriorsGuild = new AnimationGame(this);
  return warriorsGuild;
 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check object.getId() from InventoryOptionsHandler class. I think your id is null then causes NullPointerException.